# Function to evaluate any expression/condition on a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, sympy

I have a dataframe df with few columns

```
Sub2_marks Sub1_marks Total_marks
30         40         90
40         60         80
20         100        90
0          0           0
```

above is a sample.

I need to compute few expressions/validations on this dataframe.
Currently i am using sympy function as below

```
def fn_validate(formula,**args):
    exp=sy.sympify(formula)
    exp=exp.subs(args)
    return exp
```

I am calling above function using apply method as below

```
df['check_1']=df.apply(lambda row:fn_validate('X<=Y',X=row['Sub2_marks'],Y=row['Total_marks']),axis=1)

df['check_2']=df.apply(lambda row:fn_validate('X+Y<Z',X=row['Sub2_marks'],Y=row['Sub1_marks'],Z=row['Total_marks']),axis=1)

df['check_3']=df.apply(lambda row:fn_validate('X/Y<1',X=row['Sub2_marks'],Y=row['Sub1_marks']),axis=1)
```

I am looking for a function which can accept any variation of expression conditions like (Sub1_marks/Total_marks <=1) or ((Sub2_marks+Sub1_marks)/Total_marks <=1) etc.. and evaluate the results into a new column in the same dataframe. 
 Problem I am facing, is in case of 0 values, I am getting error.

```
Invalid Nan Comparison
```

I cant remove this values from the dataframe
Please let me know, is there any other way to do this expression validation

Comment: can't you use `if/else` to check what you have in row and skip calculations? OR `try/except` to catch error ?

Comment: As of now, i am doing try/except.  I was trying to check whether any other approach i can follow.

Comment: you don't know what variables will be used in `formula` so you can't check these columns if there is no `NAN`. Probably you would have to write parser to check what variables are used in formula - so it could be too complicated. OR you would have to remove/replace all `NAN` at start but still can be other problem which can get error.